# Janus GridEX: how to expand rows

Tags: c#, .net, janus, gridex

I've been using Janus GridEX control in hierarchical mode and I want all rows to be expanded.

As I said before I'm using hierarchy, no groups so `expandGroups()` does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

grid.ExpandRecords();

Answer (score 0):

I just had the issue myself.
`grid.ExpandRecords()` is the correct method. But it will only work if the grid is visible and actually displayed.

In my case I'm using a TabControl. I had to use the `grid.ExpandRecords()` method in the `SelectedTabChanged` event